# ORA-29538: Java not installed - PL/SQL calling a java code

Tags: java, database, oracle, plsql

i'm getting a problem to run PL/SQL code calling Java code, that is my PL/SQL Code

```
create or replace function hello return varchar2 as language java name 'Hello.hello() return java.lang.String';

declare
  batman varchar2(5000) := hello;
begin
  DBMS_output.put_line('batman ' || batman);
end;
```

My code is just a method called "hello", returning a string, i've used javac Hello.java to compile the java file, but it continues returning the same error.

Full error Stack:

```
ORA-29538: Java não instalado
ORA-06512: em "COTRIJAL_TESTE.HELLO", line 1
ORA-06512: em line 2
29538. 00000 -  "Java not installed"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to use a Java command when Java is not installed.
*Action:   Install Java, or do not use the command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle XE lacks Java.  Use full version of Oracle.

Comment: Humm, but i can use only Oracle XE, there's no way to run a java code using pl sql using XE?